# Using a specific SQL Server schema for ADX external table

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-explorer

I want to define an [external table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/external-sql-tables#syntax) in Azure Data Explorer, pointing to an Azure SQL Server view in a specific schema (i.e. *not* the `dbo` schema or the user's default schema).

For example, view `ABC`, in database `ACME` with schema `XYZ` (thus fully qualified: `ACME.XYZ.ABC`).

If I alter the user account (in SQL Server) used to connect to SQL Server, and set the default schema to `XYZ`, the creation will succeed.

For example:

```sql
ALTER USER ADX_Reader WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = XYZ;
```

```
.create-or-alter external table ABC (
    <omitted for brevity>
)
kind = sql
table = ABC
(
    h@"<connection string>"
)
```

Is there any way to create an external table that points to a SQL Server table/view in a non-default schema?

Notes:

- The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/external-sql-tables#syntax) mention "*Altering the schema or format of an external SQL table is not supported.*", however *schema* in this context seems to mean structure instead of the actual database schema (bit of a terminology clash).
- It's not possible to add the schema to the table name in the `create` command (citing the docs): "*The name of the SQL table. Not including the database name (example: `MySqlTable` and not `db1.MySqlTable`). If the name of the table contains a period (".") you can use `['Name.of.the.table']` notation.*" - It seems as they forgot about the existence of a schema altogether.

Comment: Doesn’t specifying the fully-qualified name of the SQL table work?

.create external table NAME (…) kind=sql table=['ACME.XYZ.ABC'] (…)

Comment: @Avnera Yes, that works! I thought I tested it, but perhaps I skipped it because of the remark about tables with a period in it. Thank you! If you put your comment in an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: Great! the docs will be updated next week. Thanks much for raising our attention to this.